# How to show line number on side right QPlainTextEdit in Qt

Tags: qt, show, line-numbers, rights

I am just learning Qt. I want to show line number of `QPlainTextEdit`. I found this link http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html
and it worked. But now I want `QPlainTextEdit` to show line number with other controls on the form as in the image below.

[image: How to show line number on QT]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The example from doc.qt.io that you've cited does exactly what you are asking. They subclassed `QPlainTextEdit` and extended it accordingly. If you just need line numbers, simply delete extra functionality from that example.